# SQLCE Mobile Application SqlCeResultSet DISPLAY/EDIT

Tags: datagridview, sql-server-ce

I've seen many examples of quick-and-dirty, nice-and-neat, SERVER EXPLORER-to-form, drag-and-drop--generation of code.

What about data that will be generated, on-the-fly, to be presented on (a) windows form(s)--for possible EDITs?  There doesn't appear to be a way to quickly, and painlessly generate some drag-and-drop stuff--if the data doesn't already exist!

My questions are:

1. I am developing a MOBILE application--so is the DataGridView available?  (I don't see it in the TOOLBOX)
2. I'd like to use the SqlCeResultSet when I select the data to be displayed on my form(s)--for possible EDITs.  How do I get the data bound and DISPLAYED on my form(s)--in preparation for EDITs?

robertd903@msn.com